# Alternative complete bases for Fourier Series.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Knowing that
$$\left\{ \sin\left(kx\right)\right\} _{k\in\mathbb{N}}$$
and
$$\left\{ \cos\left(kx\right)\right\} _{k\in\mathbb{N\cup}\left\{ 0\right\} }$$

are complete systems in $L^2(0,\pi)$. How would we prove that
$$\left\{ \sin\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right)\right\} _{k\in\mathbb{N}}$$
and
$$\left\{ \cos\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right)\right\} _{k\in\mathbb{N\cup}\left\{ 0\right\} }$$
are also complete systems that generate any function $f\in{L^2(0,\pi)}$?

I have been using this to solve PDE's with robin conditions. It works, but I don't see any justification why this can be done.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your definition complete system?

Comment: I mean a system of independent functions that generate any function of $L^2(0,\pi)$ with infinite linear combinations (fourier series).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to show that

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \sin{\left [ \left (k+\frac{1}{2}  \right)x \right]} \sin{\left [ \left (k'+\frac{1}{2}  \right)x \right]} = \begin{cases} \\ 0 & k \ne k'\\ M_k & k = k'\end{cases}$$

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \sin{\left [ \left (k+\frac{1}{2}  \right)x \right]} \cos{\left [ \left (k'+\frac{1}{2}  \right) x \right]} = \begin{cases} \\ 0 & k \ne k'\\ N_k & k = k'\end{cases}$$

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \cos{\left [ \left (k+\frac{1}{2}  \right)x \right]} \cos{\left [ \left (k'+\frac{1}{2}  \right)x \right]} = \begin{cases} \\ 0 & k \ne k'\\ P_k & k = k'\end{cases}$$

where $M_k$, $N_k$, and $P_k$ are nonzero normalization factors.

Comment: This is easy to show. But it just shows that the functions are ortogonal. It does not show they generate $L^2(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Aha, I see.  Well, look at it this way: the new function elements you describe are linear combinations of elements of a complete set of old function elements over the same space.  In that case, the new function elements would form a complete set because you can show that Cauchy sequences of series of such functions converge to any element of $L^2(0,\pi)$, since series involving the old function elements do so.

Comment: It is supposed there is a way to prove it from using the standard bases of sinuses only and cosinuses only.

Comment: Yes, that was my point.  The "old" functions would be those sines and cosines.

Comment: Yes, but I mean a more simple way. By doing a geometric argument. I recall to have heard it in the university long ago.

Comment: It is something very standard in PDE's to uses those systems. Someone must be having the nice simple answer I once heard.

Comment: You mean something akin to a rotation of axes?  Kind of like, if the original sines and cosines represented one set of axes, then the new set of sines and cosines represent a rotated set of axes.